# Where did Nanavira Thera deviate from the commentaries

Tags: pali-canon

I came across that the Ven. sir (http://www.nanavira.org) interpreted the Dependent Origination without the traditional 3 lifetime interpretation.

Are there other places he deviated? What are they and what was his interpretation? How are the others who hold similar view?

Answer (score 2):

Most of it is available in his Notes on Dhamma, and some more in the Letters. In other words, anyone interested is welcome to do their homework. Some examples:

> *Cittavīthi*, ... of which so much use is made in the Visuddhimagga ... is a pure scholastic invention and has nothing at all to do with the Buddha's Teaching

...

> ... the erroneous notion of *anuloma-gotrabhu-magga-phala*, supposed to be the successive moments in the attainment of *sotāpatti*. It is sometimes thought that the word *akālika* as applied to the Dhamma means that attainment of *magga* is followed 'without interval of time' by attainment of *phala*; but this is quite mistaken.

...

> *Phassa*, 'contact', is defined ... as the coming together of the eye, forms, and eye-consciousness ... But it is probably wrong to suppose that we must therefore understand the word *phassa*, primarily at least, as contact between these three things.

Comment: I was looking for commentary vs Ven. Sir's interpretations side by side and what exactly the differences between them.